# UIBarButtonItem not in correct shape

Tags: swift, uibutton, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

I want to create a favourite button on the top right corner of my navigation bar. I want to use a star icon, so I created a UIButton and embed it in a UIBarButtonItem. However, the bar button is super wide even if I manually set the size for it.

Another problem is the picture I used here is actually a white star from Apple's introduction to iOS programming tutorial. However, it appeared on the screen as a blue star. I have no idea why.

```
let button = UIButton(type: .system)
button.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 34, height: 34)
button.setImage(UIImage(named: "filledStar"), for: .normal)
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(bookmarkCourse(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

let barButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: button)
navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barButtonItem
```

[image]

Comment: Your UIButton needs to be `.custom`, not .normal.   Also, what size is your filledStar image?  You should use assets scaled to the correct sizes: Recommended Sizes are 72px × 72px (24pt × 24pt @3x), 48px × 48px (24pt × 24pt @2x).   You can also remove the frame size if you do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly configure your `UIButton` as a custom button:

```
let button = UIButton(type: .custom)
```

Secondly, your image asset is most likely oversized.  The way I would do this is to upload rescaled images as per the guidance from Apple.  You can then also remove the line of code setting the frame size.

> Navigation Bar and Toolbar Icon Size Use the following sizes for
>   guidance when preparing custom navigation bar and toolbar icons, but
>   adjust as needed to create balance.
>
> Target sizes 72px × 72px (24pt × 24pt @3x)    48px × 48px (24pt × 24pt
>   @2x) Maximum sizes 84px × 84px (28pt × 28pt @3x)56px × 56px (28pt ×
>   28pt @2x)
>
> https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/icons-and-images/custom-icons/

Comment: I tried rescaling the image and it works. I guess this is the problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You might want not to use a `UIBarButtonItem` with a custom view. Just pass the actual image when creating the bar button:

```
let image = UIImage(named: "filledStar")
UIBarButtonItem(image: image, style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(bookmarkCourse(_:))
```

Regarding the color, that's because of your bar button item's tint color. The default is that blue you're seeing. Also, pay attention to scale you assets properly, as per @rbaldwin's comment.